# team foundation server compare with latest version

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

in tfs when performing "comparing with latest version" it used to display two windows initially one for local copy and another for machine copy(latest version) but now both the copies are shown in a single window

Comment: What do you mean by two windows, are you talking about 2 panes? and now only one pane? Check the answer below

Answer (score 1):

There is a little button at the top where you can set how the compare window show up:
[image]